# Do you have to get access to the developer's code in order to work on creating selenium tests?

Tags: selenium

I am able to create selenium tests to test a web app or website without having access to the developers' code. Is this the correct way to do selenium testing?
Do you have to get access to the developer's code in order to create selenium tests? If so, how does that work and why?

Comment: no in selenium automation only front end required HTML, CSS

Answer (score 2):

No. You do not need to access developers' codes in order to work on selenium tests.

All you need is to access HTML codes to create selenium tests.

Answer (score 2):

That is not required. As selenium can interact with web application from browser without needing any code or development team's permissions.

So in short, You don't need code access.

In some cases, you may need access of database, for example- email verification, if you need to pick some id from database to access a page etc.